# Replace curl with file_get_content

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I need to replace curl with file_get_content ( I have removed sensitive informations ):

```
curl -F 'client_id=aaa' \
    -F 'client_secret=bbb' \
    -F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
    -F 'redirect_uri=http://testtest.altervista.org/instagram/' \
    -F 'code=ccc' \
    https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token
```

I tryed this but doens't work ( it return nothing ):

```
$url = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=aaa&client_secret=bbb&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http://testtest.altervista.org/instagram/&code=ccc';
print json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
```

Why ?

Comment: what are you getting when you run that URL in browser?

Comment: you are replacing a 'shell' cURL command with a php file_get_contents ... what is your real objective here ?

Comment: When you have a URL inside a URL, the inner URL MUST be `urlencode()`ed. If you get nothing, it would be helpful to show the error log or at least the headers and status code returned by the call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why you want to change cURL to a file_get_contents, but I would at least make sure to encode the querystring you're trying to use. You could use [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to get proper results

```
$query = array(
    'client_id' => 'aaa',
    'client_secret' => 'bbb',
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://testtest.altervista.org/instagram/',
    'code' => 'ccc
);

$domain = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token?'
$url = $domain . http_build_query($data);
print json_decode( file_get_contents($url) );
```